# Setting a div's display to none hides all child divs

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a page that contains a couple of divs, whose display are set to none, and then toggled via jquery whenever a user clicks on an associated li :

```
<ul id="switches">
    <li id="home" style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer">HOME</li>
    <li id="vouchers" style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer">GIFT VOUCHERS</li>
    <li id="reservations" style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer">RESERVATIONS</li>       
    <li id="contact">
        <img src="images/loc.png" style="cursor : hand; cursor: pointer" />
    </li>
    <li id="menu">
        <img src="images/menu.png" style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

The switching code I got from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710/914602

Whenever someone clicks the "home" li, I show the "content_home" div, etc.

```
<div id="content" style="float: right; width: 500px; margin-top: 15px">
    <div id="content_home" class="active">
        home
    </div>
    <div id="content_vouchers">
        voucher
    </div>
    <div id="content_reservations">
        reserv
    </div>
    <div id="content_contact">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:480px; margin-left:20px; height:300px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_menu">
        menu
    </div>
</div>
```

On my "content_contact" div, I have another div, that I set to contain a Google Map (see here : http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/).

However, if the "content_contact" div's display is set to none (by clicking one of the other links), all the divs it contains are also hidden. When I set the display to block again, **only** the parent is set, not the children. (so... If I click "home", "content_home" is displayed. When I then click on "contact", "content_contact" is displayed, but the divs it contains (including the map)'s display is still set to none).

If I enumerate over all "content_contact"'s children, setting their display to block again, sure, the map div is displayed, but all the divs **inside** the map are also shown (stuff like the Map Data overlay, menu for selecting Satellite/Road style map, the Streetview menu etc) :

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [1sttime.co.za](http://www.1sttime.co.za/error.jpg))</sub>

Is there a way to only set the parent div to be invisible, while keeping the children as they are?

Comment: Can you post your javascript code where you hide the divs?

Comment: My divs were set to display:none by default, and whenever I'd activate (show) one, I'd addClass a class containing display:block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it has to do with how you are hiding your other content.

I have a simplified example here that seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/3WSnD/

Remove the '>' from `$('#content > div').hide();` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  All elements have their own display values but by design if a parent has display:none then it's child elements will not be shown either.  You would have to remove #map_canvas from within #content_contact if you want it to be displayed while it's parent is hidden.

The map issue may be unique to Google Maps which doesn't play nice with display:none.  Instead of setting it to display:none you may want to try positioning it absolutely and moving it way off screen (ex: left:99999px) and then bringing it back when you want to display it again.

Comment: I don't want to display #map_canvas when it's parent is hidden. When the parent is hidden, and is shown again, #map_canvas is not displayed.